# Macro created in VBA on Office 2010 has different behaviour on Office 2016

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2016

I have a macro that processes a list of worksheets with data. The whole process is monitored by a form which displays the status and the worksheet being processed. After upgrading the Office version from 2010 to 2016 my monitoring form is hidden by an Excel empty window until the whole processing ends.

How can I bring back my status window in foreground as was the case before Office upgrade?

```
Private Sub InitializeForm()
    If myInfoForm Is Nothing Then
        Set myInfoForm = New FrmAuswerteInfo
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Show()
    If Not myVisible Then
        Call InitializeForm
        Call myInfoForm.Show
    End If
    myVisible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the form modal? How is it being displayed? What's the processing in question and does it toggle `Application.ScreenUpdating`? We're going to need a [mcve] here...

Comment: What means that my form is modal? I have created a form that has Init, Update, Show, Hide, Dispose methods. In Init the initialization is being made and also an object which contains data regarding the evaluation process is being sent as argument. In update the message which will be displayed by this form is being sent as argument (for example hat processing is being done at a specific step). Show, Hide are showing hiding the form. Dispose method destroys the form object. The code in question can't be provided due to the complexity and size.

Comment: What is strange is that when debugging the processing and displaying of status window seems to look identical in Office 2016 as it is in Office 2010.

Comment: I will look over to parts of code that could be representative for the process and I will add it.

Comment: I'm using Application.ScreenUpdating after show function is called (see above code), however the evaluation form which displays the status is in background not in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Form references with `DoEvents` (e.g. below is part of some code that shall provide a status bar that updates whilst the vba is executing...)

```
With UserForm1
    .FrameProgress.Caption = Format(PctDone, "0%")
    .LabelProgress.Width = PctDone * (.FrameProgress.Width - 10)
End With
DoEvents
```

Comment: Hi @SocketIM, I recommend the following:
1) the first time you use the userform, call on it using "Userform.Show", not "Call Userform.Show".  
2) thereafter, don't call on the userform, just use a "With Userform" to update whatever information you want updated in the userform, and immediately follow the "End With" statement, with  
3) "DoEvents"  
Hope this works for you.